# Automatic div sizing to fill spacing from svg on screen resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the 4 colored divs around the black svg, to fill in the extra width or height of the blank space (the pink) when the screen is resized. There's a pink div behind the logo, to give you and example of the space that needs to be filled by the 4 colored divs. Is something like this possible in pure CSS and HTML or is JS needed? Any info on this helps, thanks.

```html
<style>
ul {
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 77%;
}

li {
  display: block;
  font-size:17px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.navtext{
  background-color:orange;
  width: 35%;
  height:20%;
  right:0px;
  position:absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header{
background-color:yellow;
width:100%;
height:20%;
}

.logo{
  position:absolute;
  left:5%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  height:20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logotext{
  font-size:27px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.front {
  background-color:blue;
  height: 81vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width:100%;
}

.video {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/107/800/800) center/cover;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: -100vh;
  position: sticky;
  width:100%;
  top: 0;
}

.container {
  height:200vh;
}

.right{
right:0px;
width:50%;
Height:91%;
position:absolute;
background-color:pink;
/*display: flex;*/
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.logoanimecont{
  text-align:center;
  width:75%;
  margin:auto;
  
}

.left{
width:50%;
Height:91%;
background-color:green;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.titlebox {
  text-align:center;
  width:75%;
  background-color:purple;
  margin:auto;
  
}

.title {
  font-size:30px;
  text-align:center;
  
}

.hide{ display:none }

.rightbordertop{
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
  background-color:red;
}

.rightborderbottom{
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
  bottom:0px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:darkgrey;
}

.rightborderleft{
  width:25%;
  height:75%;
  background-color:brown;
}

.rightborderright{
  right:0px;
  height:75%;
  width:25%;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
}

svg {  position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;}
    </style>



<div class="container">
  <div class="front">
  <div class="header">
      <div class="logo">
        <span class="logotext">f-e</span>
      </div>
   <div class="nav">
        <div class="navtext">
          <ul>
           <li><a href="#home">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#news">Services</a></li>
           <li><a href="#contact">Clients</a></li>
           <li><a href="#about">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="titlebox">
        <span class="title">Random text, centered v and h.</span>
      </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="rightbordertop"></div>
        <div class="rightborderright"></div>
        <div class="rightborderleft"></div>
        <div class="rightborderbottom"></div>
        <div class="logoanimacont">
      <div class="logoanime">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 70 70">
            <path id="metabolism" d="M0,0v72h72V0H0z M45.38,12.19l-1.21,1.66c-0.16,0.23-0.35,0.26-0.57,0.09c-1.47-1-2.85-1.18-4.13-0.53
c-1.41,0.75-2.11,2.19-2.11,4.31v9.47h4.62c0.28,0,0.42,0.15,0.42,0.44v2.06c0,0.29-0.14,0.44-0.42,0.44h-4.62v23.85
c0,0.29-0.14,0.44-0.42,0.44h-2.02c-0.26,0-0.39-0.15-0.39-0.44V30.14H31.8c-0.28,0-0.42-0.15-0.42-0.44v-2.06
c0-0.29,0.14-0.44,0.42-0.44h2.72v-9.47c0-1.58,0.32-2.98,0.97-4.19c0.64-1.23,1.55-2.15,2.72-2.75c1.09-0.56,2.25-0.77,3.5-0.63
c1.25,0.12,2.44,0.59,3.59,1.41C45.53,11.73,45.56,11.94,45.38,12.19z"/>
  
            <path id="technique" class="hide" d="M0,0v72h72V0H0z M40.05,36.57c0,0.22-0.11,0.33-0.33,0.33h-8.62c-0.22,0-0.33-0.11-0.33-0.33V35
c0-0.2,0.11-0.3,0.33-0.3h8.62c0.22,0,0.33,0.1,0.33,0.3V36.57z"/>
            
            <path id="digital" class="hide" d="M0,0v72h72V0H0z M45.89,36.15c0,0.19-0.09,0.29-0.28,0.3l-16.83,1.48c0.47,1.7,1.41,3.1,2.81,4.2
c1.44,1.11,3.06,1.66,4.88,1.66c1.38,0,2.66-0.34,3.87-1.01c1.19-0.66,2.15-1.56,2.88-2.72c0.11-0.19,0.26-0.23,0.45-0.12
l1.36,0.77c0.19,0.12,0.23,0.28,0.12,0.47c-0.94,1.48-2.18,2.66-3.73,3.52c-1.53,0.86-3.18,1.29-4.95,1.29
c-2.81,0-5.21-0.99-7.2-2.98c-2-2-3-4.41-3-7.22c0-2.86,0.96-5.27,2.88-7.24c1.91-1.97,4.24-2.95,7.01-2.93
c2.69,0.02,4.98,1.01,6.89,2.98c1.89,1.95,2.84,4.3,2.84,7.03V36.15z"/>
           </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="video"></div>
</div>

<div style="height:150vh"> more content later </div>
```

Comment: deleting and repeating the same question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/65543965/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/65555333/8620333) won't help you. Either wait or edit your question to give more details but please stop spamming the site with the same question (you will simply end with a quesiton ban)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to re-write using flexbox to obtain what I wanted. Incase anyone comes across a problem similar, im posting my answer because it achieved what I needed after re-writing the code.

```css
html, body{
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#container{
  background-color:pink;
  height:91%;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
}

#left{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  display:flex;
  position:relative;
}

#right{
  width:50%;
  background-color:lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right>* {
        flex: 1 1;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  margin:auto;
  max-width:calc(80vh - 25px);
  background-color:purple;
  left:0;
}
#logo:before {
  content:"";
  display:flex;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

#rightsidetop{
  background-color:orange;
}

#rightsidebottom{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="right">
    <div id="rightsidetop"></div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="rightsidebottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do it, but without information what do blue and red containers contain content wise, we can only guess. One suggestion though, don't use `position: absolute` that much, master flex layout [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). This solution requires grouping of central three sections into one (maroon, pink and blue containers are now wrapped in `div` with inline style):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 91%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hide { display: none }

.rightbordertop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: red;
}

.rightborderbottom{
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.rightborderleft{
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: brown;
}

.rightborderright{
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
    <div class="rightbordertop"></div>
    <div style="height: 50%; display: flex;">
      <div class="rightborderleft"></div>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 70 70">
        <path id="metabolism" d="M0,0v72h72V0H0z M45.38,12.19l-1.21,1.66c-0.16,0.23-0.35,0.26-0.57,0.09c-1.47-1-2.85-1.18-4.13-0.53
c-1.41,0.75-2.11,2.19-2.11,4.31v9.47h4.62c0.28,0,0.42,0.15,0.42,0.44v2.06c0,0.29-0.14,0.44-0.42,0.44h-4.62v23.85
c0,0.29-0.14,0.44-0.42,0.44h-2.02c-0.26,0-0.39-0.15-0.39-0.44V30.14H31.8c-0.28,0-0.42-0.15-0.42-0.44v-2.06
c0-0.29,0.14-0.44,0.42-0.44h2.72v-9.47c0-1.58,0.32-2.98,0.97-4.19c0.64-1.23,1.55-2.15,2.72-2.75c1.09-0.56,2.25-0.77,3.5-0.63
c1.25,0.12,2.44,0.59,3.59,1.41C45.53,11.73,45.56,11.94,45.38,12.19z"/>
       </svg>
      <div class="rightborderright"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightborderbottom"></div>
    <div class="logoanimacont"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close, however when you shrink the bowser size the pink shows on the top and bottom borders. he blue and brown side divs work but the top and bottom ones dont. Great example though!

Comment: It's like that on purpose. When you squeeze the window that much, maroon and blue areas will not be visible. That will happen on a certain breakpoint, on mobile devices for example, when width of device is smaller than its height. At that point, you'll probably want to change `flex-direction` of container that holds maroon, pink and blue containers, and shift maroon and blue areas to be over and under the pink one.

Comment: Ahh okay, I see. How would I increase the size of the SVG with your code? Can't get in functioning.

Comment: Please provide an image of what you are trying to achieve. In current solution, height of SVG is defined in `div` element which wraps maroon, pink and blue container. Currently, it is 50% of height of whole container, defined in inline styles.

Comment: Just need the SVG to be larger

Comment: Yes, but additional info about enlarging is needed. For instance: 1) should it be larger in every situation, or just when you squeeze the window in width and pink background shows above and below the SVG 2) how much larger should it be 3) should SVG dimensions be fixed or flexible

Comment: Should be larger in every situation while maintaining the shrink when the window is squeezed. 1.5x as large and SVG dimensions should always have the same width and height.

Comment: 2can say 2x as larger for ease of use

Comment: Well, that's a weird layout :D Change `.rightbordertop ` and `.rightbordertop` classes height property from 25% to 12.5% and then, change the height property in inline styles of container that wraps maroon, pink and blue container, from 50% to 75% (that would be 1.5x larger)

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity stake, I focused only on the right side of you page, where the `svg` is surrounded by the four `div`. Also be aware that I used new `class` names to make the code easier to understand.

I used `flexbox` one level at a time to achieve this effect. You can use the new `.container` `div` and place it wherever you wish on your page (just be aware of the possible conflicting `class` names with your current project).

**NOTE**: Run the code snippet on full screen so you can test the effect.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: dimgray;
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  height: 100%;
  background: brown;
  flex: 1;
}

.center {
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

svg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 70 70">
        <rect width="100" height="100" /></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting way to achieve something similar

Comment: But it is the same, you just need to add this code to your existing code to have what you one.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add this new example to show that the my last answer can and will achieve the desired effect. One just need to add the specifics of the project (which are unknown to us).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vh;
}

.nav {
  background: orange;
  width: 35%;
  height: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: purple;
}

.left-column {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.right-column {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: dimgray;
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  height: 100%;
  background: brown;
  flex: 1;
}

.center {
  width: 30%;
  /* size of the svg */
  height: auto;
}

.right {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

svg {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="nav"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-column">
    <div class="content">Center and Middle Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="left"></div>
      <div class="center">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 70 70">
          <rect width="100" height="100" />
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Only issue is if you try resizing your browser or window the elements fall outside of the parent div

Comment: change the size of the center to 90 or 100% and youll see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this problem comes with the fact that you are using an absolute value for the height of the columns. Since by using an absolute height you are preventing the column to expand, then the `center` will go beyond is container. To prevent this, you need to use another specific size for the `center` that is less that is parent (in other word, you cannot use 90 or 100 in this case).

Comment: Remember that this is one of the many problems of using absolute heights and widths, that the design becomes less responsive (or something not responsive at all) depending of the size of the browser. But again, this is due to the original layout. If you want to accomplish a responsive resizing of this element, the you need to get rid of the absolute heights and width and let the content (and the browser) decide. One or the other, but you cannot have both.